# For n even, does Fermat Theorem reduce to the Pythagorean Theorem?

Tags: geometry, number-theory

For n even, does Fermat theorem

$a^n+b^n=c^n$

reduce to Pythagorean theorem

$x^2+y^2=z^2$

where $x=a^{n/2},y=b^{n/2},z=c^{n/2}$ **must** be a Pythagorean triple?

For example,

[image]

Let $n=8$, then

$a^8+b^8=c^8$

can be re-written as

$(a^4)^{2}+(b^4)^{2}=(c^4)^{2}$

Let $x=a^4, y=b^4, z=c^4$, so that

$x^2+y^2=z^2$

[image]

Does showing that no such Pythagorean triple exists, prove Fermat's Theorem for $n=2k$.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, for $n$ even, say $n=2k$, the equation reduces to saying that $(a^k,b^k,c^k)$ is a Pythagorean triple (not necessarily primitive), so if you can show that no such pythagorean triple exists for $k\gt 1$, you would prove Fermat's last theorem for the case of even $n\gt 2$, but I don't see how you would proceed...

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Concerning your title equation. No, it does not reduce. We have infinitely many nontrivial integral solutions to $x^2+y^2=z^2$, but *no* nontrivial integral solution to $x^4+y^4=z^4$. You only state that $x^{2n}+y^{2n}=z^{2n}$ can be rewritten as $(x^n)^2+(y^n)^2=(z^n)^2$, i.e., with quadratic exponent.

Comment: Thanks Prasun for confirming my logic. I have no idea how to proceed further, but narrowing the search to just Pythagorean triples looked interesting. :)